# React PropType for one or multiple types of the same class

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Trying to check a propType for children that are of a specific type. 
I tried the following but got this error.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not
>   callable

```
import Button from '../Button';

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.instanceOf(Button),
  }
```

I'd like to check that either one or multiple Button elements can be children and no other type can be children.

Comment: should it be `instanceOf(Input)`?

Comment: Sorry that was miss type. No it should be Button.

Comment: how does `Button` look like?

Comment: Its just a very simple React component.

Comment: But there could be multiple or one composed in as children to my component that is handling the propTypes.